# VEGA GRAPH - Get top hit with filter

Tags: kibana, vega, vega-lite

I have this Index

ST         ID         time
0           1           12:04
1           1          12:00
0          2          12:02
1          2          11:58
0          2          11:22
1          3          12:33
0          3          12:20

I'm trying to get a graph that could shows the top hit(last document indexed in elastic for each ID) when ST = 0 to have results as

ST          ID          time
0           1           12:04
0          2          12:02

As you could see ID = 3 has top hit with ST = 1, so it shouldn't appear in the table

Could someone help me with this?

BR

Answer (score 0):

In Vega-Lite, you could use an aggregate transform followed by a filter transform. For example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ST": 0, "ID": 1, "time": "12:04"},
      {"ST": 1, "ID": 1, "time": "12:00"},
      {"ST": 0, "ID": 2, "time": "12:02"},
      {"ST": 1, "ID": 2, "time": "11:58"},
      {"ST": 0, "ID": 2, "time": "11:22"},
      {"ST": 1, "ID": 3, "time": "12:33"},
      {"ST": 0, "ID": 3, "time": "12:20"}
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"time": "date:'%H:%M'"}}
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "max", "field": "time", "as": "time"},
        {"op": "argmax", "field": "time", "as": "argmax"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["ID"]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.argmax.ST == 0"}
  ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"type": "ordinal", "field": "ID"},
    "x": {"type": "temporal", "field": "time"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I will test it asap

Comment: I have to do it for Vega in Kibana, I will try to do it today.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>  Hi Jakevdp, first thing is nice to meet u! :D

I'm trying to do this in Kibana, with Vega Graph, the problem now is to change this code

"transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "max", "field": "time", "as": "time"},
        {"op": "argmax", "field": "time", "as": "argmax"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["ID"]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.argmax.ST == 0"}
  ],

To insert it in Kibana-Vega Graph to attack Elastic, is this possible?
</body>
```